# fmt.Println can change the value of the array?

Tags: go

```
var x struct {
    a bool
    b int16
    c []int32
}

func main() {
    //a := []int32{1 << 9}
    //x.c = a
    pb := (*[]int8)(unsafe.Pointer(uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&x)) + unsafe.Offsetof(x.c)))
    *pb = []int8{5}
    println(x.c[0])  // 5
    println(x.c[0])  // 5
    fmt.Println(x.c[0])  // 5
    fmt.Println(x.c[0])  // 327685 why????????
}
```

fmt.Println the same x.c[0] twice, but got different result. why?

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/Sfl5zjIfQYp the behavior does not like your describe. I think you need to add more detail in your question.

Comment: I'm not sure this is *off topic* so much as: well, you used `unsafe`, so you broke things. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Using `unsafe`, you placed an `int8` slice whose underlying array is allocated in stack in place of an `int32` slice. So, now you have a situation where the runtime thinks there is an array of `int32` values, but in fact the array is an array of `int8` values. So when `fmt.Println` reads from it, you read the byte containing the `5` you placed there, plus any junk that happens to be there.

Run it a few times, with different values, and check the bit pattern. You'll get a value where the LSB is always 5. You're reading an `int32` from a memory location into which you placed an `int8` value 5. The remaining three bytes are stack leftover values.

If you initialize your slice with `[]int8{5,0,0,0}`, you'll always get 5.

Comment: correct & precise!

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine in `go playground`.
The output always gives you `5`.
`fmt.Println` doesn't change the `x.c[0]` value

Code :

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unsafe"
)

var x struct {
    a bool
    b int16
    c []int32
}

func main() {
    //a := []int32{1 << 9}
    //x.c = a
    pb := (*[]int8)(unsafe.Pointer(uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&x)) + unsafe.Offsetof(x.c)))
    *pb = []int8{5}
    println(x.c[0])     // 5
    println(x.c[0])     // 5
    fmt.Println(x.c[0]) // 5
    fmt.Println(x.c[0]) // 327685 why????????
}
```

output:

```
5
5
5
5
```

link: https://play.golang.org/p/8l1Vj9of2vR